# Error in wildfly 8.1.0 making a EJB remote invocation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

i have made an application in `wildly 8.1.0` that uses a EJB remote session bean, but when i do the lookup i get this error:

```
EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:rb, moduleName:remot, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@75f1b0bc
```

I have configured the application.xml file and module.xml file to use the `"rb"` application name and `"remot"` module name. When I start the server, It starts without errors, and deploys the `EJB`, so i think the problem is in the client, this is the code of the client:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private static void busquedaServidor(Server.DatosRegistro datos) throws NamingException
    {        
        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming);
        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        final String appName = "rb";

        final String moduleName = "remot";

        final String distinctName = "";

        final String beanName = Ejb.class.getSimpleName();

        final String viewClassName = EjbRemote.class.getName();

        String url = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;
        //ejb:rb/remot//Ejb!Server.EjbRemote

        System.out.println(url);
        EjbRemote envio= (EjbRemote) context.lookup(url);
        envio.datosRegistro(datos);**
    }
```

Maybe the error is in the distinct name, that is empty, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue on wildfly 10.1.
I solved replacing "ejb:" with "/". In your case:

```
 String url = "/" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;
```

And the remote context got with:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://" + host + ":" + port);
properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "adminapp");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "adminpwd");
```

SOURCE: https://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/26/jboss-eap-wildfly-three-ways-to-invoke-remote-ejbs/

Hope it helps.